# Host Sub Application to main application with out change the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, dns, iis-6, azure-virtual-machine

I have one doubts, Please clarify this

We have currently host the one sub application to under main application. like below

[image: With Sub Application]

URL like

```
www.Examples.com/internal
```

**internal** is a sub application hosted under **Examples** main application.

But,  i want to host the sub application as main application like below

[image: Parllel Application]

But, the URL should be same like

```
www.Examples.com/internal
```

Note: Internal application maintain in single server or different server but, the URL should be same.

Is there any posibilities to maintain website like this?

Thanks,
Mathan Kumar H J

Answer (score 0):

A more common way is having your root zone, `example.com`, and making other projects DNS records on that zone, for example, if you host the `internal` app at Ipv4 1.2.3.4 then you would make the DNS record `internal IN A 1.2.3.4` in your zone and then `internal.example.com` will resolve to your app

Edit: noticed you do not want to change the url - if the other site is running on its own server, then you would have to get the user to that server eventually, so if you did it the `example.com/internal` way you would have to 301 redirect to that ip which would end up changing the url anyway